# Code signing macosx media type: unclear what Install4J does to a .tgz (.tar.gz) file

Tags: macos, gzip, code-signing, tar, install4j

I have been using Install4J to code sign macosx media files, and chosen for our use-case to use the`.tgz` format rather than the `.dmg` format for the media type.

And I could still use the code-signing option under the General Settings tab in the Install4J gui.

Although it is unclear what it does with the `.pk12` file I have applied to the installer.

I also compared a code signed version of the media-file to the non-code signed version, and they both can be opened using `gunzip` and `tar` or using the GUI archive managers.

What am I suppose to see in the contents of the compressed archived, when its code-signed and a `.tgz` file? Does this combination of features of Install4J even work?

Comment: We are using Install4j version 7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Code signing signs the application bundles in any case (DMG or tgz). If choosing DMG, the DMG is signed itself as well (this is new since macOS 10.11.5). Signed application bundles contain a file `Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, in my case, I'm using the .tgz media type and I couldn't find anything in inside the media file that looked like a certificate or some artifact used for signing the media. I would like to understand if there is a way to check a .tgz file, to verify if it has been signed and signed by a known CA.

Comment: The .tgz file itself cannot be signed. Only if it contains a generated launcher, then the application bundle is signed as I explained in my answer.

Comment: The media file does contain a generated launcher (bash script).

Another related question the selected `Executable type` (seen under `Modify Launcher`) make a difference, its selected to run as a service? Would changing it to GUI or Console application help with code-signing checks on the MacOSX?

Comment: Indeed, only GUI executables can be signed. bash scripts (that are generated by install4j for command line and service launchers) cannot be signed on macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have requested Install4J folks to mention this somewhere in the documentation, as it might not be obvious, given the spare information available in this space.

Comment: I have see the `Codesignature` folder appear inside the `.tgz` archive, after selecting the GUI options as `Executable type` in the Launcher configuration wizard.